# How to except string input entered as function parameter without quotes

Tags: python, validation, type-conversion

I am working on a function that takes numeric input for one of the parameters. I am able to catch if the argument passed in as string input is encased in quotes, but not if it's not quoted. I'm wondering how I can return an error and print a message for this case?

```
def score_input(test_name, test_score=0, invalid_message="Invalid test score!"):
    if test_score.isdigit() == False:
        return "Error, please enter only numeric values for test score"
    else:
        return f'Test name: {test_name} Test Score: {test_score:.2f}'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    display_text = score_input('big test', "k")
    print(display_text)
```

In the above case, since the "k" argument passed into the function is in quotes, the Error message successfully prints. But if I remove the quotes around k, the program stops and displays the following message:

```
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
if NameError:
    return "string without quotes passed into function"
```

Wondering how I can catch something like this and print the message

Comment: If you use `k` without quotes, that refers to a variable, not to the literal string "k".  That is an error in your programming.   I don't understand why you would do that on purpose?

Comment: The `NameError` exception is raised before the function is even called, so you wouldn't be able to handle this case within the body of the function anyway. Without the quotes this syntax just looks like a variable look-up, and the value for this apparent `k` variable will naturally have to be looked up at the time the parameters are passed to the function, which must happen before the body of the function executes.

Comment: More importantly, can you explain why you think you need to handle this scenario? The only way this problem could occur is if you or other developers working with this code deliberately write a variable look-up for a variable that you know does not exist, in which case, why would you do that? AND what would your custom error handling code provide that the default unhandled Python exception doesn't already provide?

Comment: More food for thought: An end-user of your script will not be tampering with your source code, right? They will simply run the script the way you've written it. At what point do you expect an end-user to be able to run into this error?

Comment: Thanks Paul and John for your help, I wasn't sure if I would actually get a response! I'm still new to programming, and after reading your responses and thinking about it I'm realizing that I think my question was basically unnecessary. I was envisioning a user-input scenario if I were to include an input prompt, but now realizing in that scenario the validation would be different than this. I just wanted to make sure that I was covering all possible inputs to this function but without a user-input component it's not really an issue. I really appreciate that you guys responded, thanks again!